# C# Windows Form Countdown Timer

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, countdown

I've got 3 textboxes, (Hours, Minutes, Seconds), a start, pause and stop button and I am using labels to show the current timer. I also have a timer with an interval of `1000`. My question is why won't this display the time using the labels? Everything else works, it just won't register that I've put values in the textboxes.

#### Code

Start Timer:

```
    private void startbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (paused != true) //Timer is not paused (active)
        {

            int.TryParse(textBoxhrs.Text, out hours);
            int.TryParse(textBoxmin.Text, out minutes);
            int.TryParse(textBoxsec.Text, out seconds);

            if (hours >= 1 || (minutes >= 1) || (seconds >= 1))

            //If there is at least one integer entered in any of the 3 boxes, executes; else - //throws an exception
            {
                startbutton.Enabled = true;
                pausebutton.Enabled = true; //changed the value to 'true'  
                stopbutton.Enabled = true; //changed the value to 'true'
                textBoxhrs.Enabled = false;
                textBoxmin.Enabled = false;
                textBoxsec.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Enter at least one integer!");
            }
        }
    }

    private void stopbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Stop the timer. 
        paused = false;
        timer1.Enabled = false;
        startbutton.Enabled = true; //changed to true
        stopbutton.Enabled = false; //changed to false
        pausebutton.Enabled = false; //changed to false
        textBoxsec.Clear();
        textBoxmin.Clear();
        textBoxhrs.Clear();
        textBoxhrs.Enabled = true;
        textBoxsec.Enabled = true;
        textBoxmin.Enabled = true;
        textBoxhrs.Enabled = true;
        lblHr1.Text = "00";
        lblMin1.Text = "00";
        lblSec1.Text = "00";
        MessageBox.Show("Timer is Stopped, to re-start press <Start>"); //updated to give user a chance to run the timer again after stoppage.

    }
```

Pause Button:

```
    private void pausebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Pause the timer. 
        timer1.Enabled = false;
        paused = true; //
        startbutton.Enabled = true; // changed to true
        pausebutton.Enabled = false; //changed to false
    }
```

Timer:

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Verify if the time didn't pass.
        if ((minutes == 0) && (hours == 0) && (seconds == 0))
        {
            // If the time is over, clear all settings and fields.
            // Also, show the message, notifying that the time is over.
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            MessageBox.Show(textBoxMsg.Text);
            pausebutton.Enabled = false;
            stopbutton.Enabled = false;
            startbutton.Enabled = true;
            textBoxMsg.Clear();
            textBoxsec.Clear();
            textBoxmin.Clear();
            textBoxhrs.Enabled = true;
            textBoxMsg.Enabled = true;
            textBoxsec.Enabled = true;
            textBoxmin.Enabled = true;
            textBoxhrs.Enabled = true;
            lblHr1.Text = "00";
            lblMin1.Text = "00";
            lblSec1.Text = "00";
        }
        else
        {
            // Else continue counting.
            if (seconds < 1)
            {
                seconds = 59;
                if (minutes == 0)
                {
                    minutes = 59;
                    if (hours != 0)
                        hours -= 1;

                }
                else
                {
                    minutes -= 1;
                }
            }
            else
                seconds -= 1;
            // Display the current values of hours, minutes and seconds in
            // the corresponding fields.
            lblHr1.Text = hours.ToString();
            lblMin1.Text = minutes.ToString();
            lblSec1.Text = seconds.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do i do that?

EDIT: Thanks :D done it :)

Comment: Click on the green tick outline below the answer votes.  You only need to do it if they actually answer the question, but it would be worth going back over any other questions you've asked for however far back SO lets you.  Edit: Just realized one of those answers was me :)  Thanks

Comment: I would recommend using a numeric up down( aka spin button). It does not have allow illegal input, and you can set a maximum. Read more: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do two things to get it working:

You need to start the timer in startbutton_Click:

```
if (hours >= 1 || (minutes >= 1) || (seconds >= 1))

//If there is at least one integer entered in any of the 3 boxes, executes; else - //throws an exception
{
    startbutton.Enabled = true;
    ...
    timer1.Enabled = true;
}
```

You need to hook up the timer Tick event to timer1_Tick.  You can do this by selecting the timer and clicking on the lightning bolt toolbar icon on the Properties frame, then selecting timer1_Tick for Tick.

Comment: Thanks! This worked properly, i combined it with the timer.Start(), and stop code and it's better now!

Answer (score 2):

There are other issues w/ the code, but the reason you dont see the labels update is because you never actually start the timer.

In the start click you need to add:

```
...
stopbutton.Enabled = true; //changed the value to 'true'
textBoxhrs.Enabled = false;
textBoxmin.Enabled = false;
textBoxsec.Enabled = false;

timer1.Start();  //<-- start the timer object
```

Comment: or you could use timer1.Enabled = true. But instead of your timer.Enabled = true or false, it would be clearer to use timer.Stop() and timer.Start() (which makes the same thing, but it's more readable)